# Why two prepositions can be used together?

Tags: prepositions

I see this sentence:

> Dividing a large writing project into separate files has disadvantages, though, especially if you are doing your own desktop publishing **from within** Word.

I am confusing that why two prepositions can be used together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question. I have edited it to say "prepositions". "Propositions" means something else (a common mistake).

Some prepositions, especially **from**, can precede a prepositional phrase that begins with another preposition. It is easier to understand for an example like:

- I removed the cat **from under** the sofa.

This means that the cat *was* **under** the sofa, and the speaker took the cat **from** there (the space below the sofa).

*Doing your own desktop publishing **from within** Word* is a more abstract and nuanced example. It is similar to saying you are working **from** home, and more specifically, you are working **from inside** your garage. In this case **from** does not indicate literal motion, but it emphasizes that you are virtually "going to" work from the inside of your garage.